# Proof Verification: Lemma 13.1 in Munkres

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Munkres's Lemma 13.1 states:

> Let $X$ be a set; let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$. Then $\mathcal{T}$ equals the collection of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

If I understand the proof strategy correctly, what I need to show, first, is that every union of basis elements is contained in $\mathcal{T}$, and that every element of $\mathcal{T}$ is in fact a union of basis elements. Here is what I have, if so, which is a slight rewrite of Munkres's proof.

> First, I claim that each basis element is an element of $\mathcal{T}$. Indeed, given $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x \in B$, we have $x \in B \subset B$ where $B \in \mathcal{B}$, so by definition, $B \in \mathcal{T}$. As $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology, as we just proved, $\bigcup\limits_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B \in \mathcal{T}$. That is, any union of basis elements is contained in $\mathcal{T}$. Next we show that every element of $\mathcal{T}$ is a union of basis elements. Let $U \in \mathcal{T}$. So, given $x \in U$, by definition there exists $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subset U$, which implies that $\bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x \subset U$. Conversely, each $x \in U$ is contained in some basis element $B_x$, and hence in $\bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x$, so $\bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x = U$. So $U$ is a union of basis elements, as desired.

How does this look? Have I correctly understood the proof strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, in his proof the first thing mentioned is that $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal T$ (all basic elements are open in $\mathcal T$) and so unions of subfamilies are in $\mathcal T$ by the definition of a topology. The reverse, that every open set is a union of elements of $\mathcal B$, you do show correctly: all $B_x, x \in U$ are a subset of $U$ hence so is their union, and every $x \in U$ is at least in *its* $B_x$ so $\bigcup_{x \in U} B_x = U$.

A "choice-free" version of the proof just uses $\mathcal{B}_U =\{B \in \mathcal B\mid B \subseteq U\}$ and then one shows in essentially the same way that $\bigcup \mathcal B_U = U$. This avoids having to "pick" $B_x$ for every $x$ in $U$ and still shows the same thing.

So the first part of your argument is nonsense. The property of being a base for $\mathcal T$ does *not* ensure that all base members are in $\mathcal T$, we need the extra assumption on the base that they are all open (and this is what Munkres does), otherwise we define a **network** for the topology, not a base.

Suppose you start with a bare set $X$ and a collection $\mathcal{B}$ satisfying the two axioms (1) and (2), then we can *define* a new topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ by saying that $\mathcal T$ is the set of all unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal B$. But if we already **have** a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ then $\mathcal{B}$ is a base **for** $\mathcal{T}$ iff $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ and also $\forall U \in \mathcal{T}: \forall x \in U: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq U$. Then lemma 13.1 says that the given $\mathcal{T}$ is actually equal to the set of all unions of from $\mathcal{B}$ so the base we use to define a topology turns out to be a base for the topology it's defining (!). And then all is well. Lemma 13.2 sort of summarises the situation again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I misunderstood, but in the first part of the argument, I was trying to show that each basis element $B$ was open by the definition of openness given a basis. Is that not correct (and we need to assume it)? I thought it was a consequence of the definition.

Comment: @BradG. The property we apply is $\forall U \in \mathcal{T}: \forall x \in U\exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq U$ and to be even able to apply it to $\mathcal{B}$ itself you already have to assume that $B \in \mathcal{T}$ to start with. So you reason in a circle. But luckily for us, Munkres *does* assume $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal T$ so we avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: I thought the property was $\forall U \subset X$? By definition, $B \subset X$, so we wouldn't need it to be an element of $\mathcal{T}$ to apply the property.

Comment: @BradG. No, it's only for $U \in \mathcal T$, because we have a base for $\mathcal T$. Munkres is very confusing here for beginning students: there are two notions of base he uses: a base for $\mathcal T$ and a "base to *define* a topology".

Comment: Would you mind explaining the difference? My apologies for not understanding.

Comment: @BradG. I added a final paragraph to my answer to explain (too long for a comment).